# Hide Next/Prev Link for multiple div and ul

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

Here is jquery prev/next function that works for only one set. if I add another ul set, the 2nd set doesn't function; Next/Prev doesn't function. I understand that I need to do some changes in the script code so that it can work with as many ul as possible.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
</ul>
<a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>
```

and the script is:

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
});
```

and with adding jquery.js to make it work of course. 
Now I want to know how to make this script above work with many ul and div without causing any issues or errors.

**Update#1:** **I thought of changing the code as below to adapt another div and ul ( say I have ul#block1 and ul#block2.. is there a better and cleaner way??**

```
 $('ul#block1 li:gt(4)').hide();$('ul#block2 li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul#block1').children('li:visible:first');
    var firstz = $('ul#block2').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul#block1').children('li:visible:last');
    var lastz = $('ul#block2').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
});
```

Comment: I didn't understood your question.

Comment: ok, I will edit and rephrase it. Thanks

Comment: if you have multiple ul will there be multiple next / prev anchors?  will these lists and anchors be wrapped in a parent div? or are you expecting that a selector of `$('ul')` is going to know which ul you are targetting?

Comment: no, they are individual, but in the same html page... I noticed that if I  have multiple ul around, the function works only for the 1st set... and Yes **$('ul')** is what I'm talking about.

Comment: what is #block1 and #block2 in there?

Comment: post a more complete html markup like the both uls and what you are trying to get from them

Comment: this is an example for if I added to ul sets with different ids since this is the only way the script understand the difference between multiple uls i.e. **<ul id="block1">** and **<ul id="block2">** and so on...

Comment: So one next and prev button to be clicked and do the same thing to all multiple ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a flag to help the script determine which pagination section you're trying to interact with. I chose to do that by wrapping them in a `<div>` with a common class.

```
<div class="pages">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>
</div>
<div class="pages">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

jQ

```
$('.pages ul').each(function() {
  $(this).children('li:gt(4)').hide();
})

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $(this).parent('.pages').find('ul li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $(this).parent('.pages').find('ul li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

Comment: sweeet. Maybe Monday won't suck after all.

Comment: you made it great, mate. Thanks